# What is the best way to archive documents in Jackrabbit Repository?

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr, content-repository

**Requirement:**
 I have a requirement, where i need to archive some of the `nt:file` nodes in the repository, which can be recovered at some later stage.
These `nt:file` nodes once archived, should not be visible if searched in the repository.
But, once recovered, they should become searchable.

**Approach:**

Move the folders to be archived under a folder e.g `Temp` under the same `workspace`. And once the user tries to recover the node, it should be moved back to where it existed. Does it seem like a right approach?

- If someone has already implemented such a functionality, one can share
  their experience and approaches, or
- What are the possible options i have to implement such functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving those nodes under a specific /archive folder sounds good to me.

You can then use access control to make them invisible to users, and implement services to move things in and out of the archive in a controlled way.

To allow users to un-archive the documents, you could leave a "shadow" node behind when moving to archive, with enough information to let authorized users un-archive documents.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Bertrand. I have one concern with this approach. After the node has been archived, if user tries to add the same node again, it will be stored. And then if the archived node is restored, it will lead to `ItemExistsException`. Is there any way, this can be avoided?

Comment: That's another reason for leaving a shadow node behind - if you move say /content/foo to /archive/foo, leave a node at /content/foo which points to the archived node, and setup that node's access control so that users cannot modify /content/foo, and maybe cannot even see it.

Comment: I can think of one more option i.e. creating a `mixinNode` with boolean property `isDeleted`. And attaching the `mixinNode` with the file node, when it is deleted. While searching, i will exclude all the `nt:file` nodes with 'isDeleted' property equal to `true` Do you see any problem in this approach?

Comment: That will certainly work, it's probably more work at the application level but that depends on how your application is structured.